# Toyota stalls when AC is turned on

Tags: toyota, ac, camry

When I start my 2008 Toyota Camry in the morning, I hear a clicking sound coming from under the hood and it seems to be on the drivers side. (This has been going on for approx. 3 months).

Now when I am driving down the road and I turn the air conditioner on the car shuts completely off, I loose power of everything, Brakes and steering including! Not good when your going 35 mph or more around winding roads and steep inclines.

I have parked the car till I can get some answers. Its not great but I can drive it and just leave the air off. Once it stalls it takes 3-4 tries to get the car to re-start.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this question is just too vague for anyone to help you. Can you add any more details?

Comment: When I star the car in the morning, I hear a clicking sound coming from under the hood and it seems to be on the drivers side.  (This has been going on for approx. 3 months) Now when I am driving down the road and I turn the air conditioner on the car shuts completely off, I loose power of everything, Brakes and steering including! Not good when your going 35 mph or more around winding roads and steep inclines. I have parked the car till I can get some answers. Its not great but I can drive it and just leave the air off.  Once it stalls it takes 3-4 tries to get the car to re-start.

Comment: Check your battery cables, thy may be corroded.